# Undo multiple changes in Cygwin's vim

Tags: undo-redo

I have two installations of vim: 7.4 in cygwin and 7.2 in a Linux virtual machine.  The vim in the virtual machine can undo multiple edits by repeatedly pressing the `u` key.  The vim in cygwin can only undo the most recent change.  Pressing it a second time is a "redo" (which in the virtual machine can be accomplished with the Ctrl-r sequence).

I would like to get the cygwin installation to be able to undo multiple edits through repeatedly pressing the u key, like it does in the virtual machine.

I have tried comparing the features included in both installations, but I have not identified what could be causing this difference in behavior.  Another post on this website suggested I could use the `.` key after using the `u` to undo multiple times, but that has not worked for me in the cygwin installation.  I also haven't found any settings in the vimrc files that seem like they would modify this behavior.

Comment: Using `.` for multiple undos doesn't work in Vim. That's a feature specific to nvi, which is an entirely different (re-)implementation of vi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to `:set nocompatible` and see if that does it.  vi had only one undo level so Vim's ability to behave differently is one of the non-compatible changes the `nocompatible` setting implements.

Comment: Simply creating a `~/.vimrc` file will also enable `'nocompatible'` mode.

Comment: Relevant documentation: `:help cpo-u` and `:help undo-two-ways`

Comment: Thanks Quincy and jamessan.  Just creating the ~/.vimrc file worked!